@google-cloud/pubsub NodeJS library throwing `Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null`
I'm implementing a service to publish messages to a Google Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
import { PubSub } from '@google-cloud/pubsub'

import type { NotificationData } from './models/notification'

class NotificationService {
  private pubsubClient: PubSub
  private topicName = 'notifications'

  constructor() {
    this.pubsubClient = new PubSub()
  }

  async publishMessage(messageData: NotificationData) {
    const data = JSON.stringify(messageData)
    const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(data)

    try {
      const messageId = await this.pubsubClient
        .topic(this.topicName)
        .publishMessage({ data: dataBuffer })

      console.log(`Message published (id: ${messageId})`)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error publishing message:', error)
    }
  }
}

export const notificationService = new NotificationService()

When I import and use the service in the front-end (vue3) component, the app fails to load with the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at node_modules/@google-cloud/paginator/build/src/resource-stream.js (@google-cloud_pubsub.js?v=ccdc38b3:46169:49)
    at __require2 (chunk-AUZ3RYOM.js?v=ccdc38b3:18:50)
    at node_modules/@google-cloud/paginator/build/src/index.js (@google-cloud_pubsub.js?v=ccdc38b3:46236:29)
    at __require2 (chunk-AUZ3RYOM.js?v=ccdc38b3:18:50)
    at node_modules/@google-cloud/pubsub/build/src/pubsub.js (@google-cloud_pubsub.js?v=ccdc38b3:63297:23)
    at __require2 (chunk-AUZ3RYOM.js?v=ccdc38b3:18:50)
    at node_modules/@google-cloud/pubsub/build/src/index.js (@google-cloud_pubsub.js?v=ccdc38b3:85020:20)
    at __require2 (chunk-AUZ3RYOM.js?v=ccdc38b3:18:50)
    at @google-cloud_pubsub.js?v=ccdc38b3:85077:16@google-cloud_pubsub.js?v=ccdc38b3:46169

This happens before the component using the service is even rendered. I can't find anyone with the same issue anywhere in the library's issues or elsewhere on stackoverflow.
